# Uninstalling Windows Updates via CMD Batch File

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, updates, uninstallation

I am trying to put together a batch script that will quietly remove a specific windows update. I have the KB #.

I cant seem to find a seamless way to do this so far. Is there a way to uninstall via a GUID of sorts? If so, how do you find the GUIDs of each specific installed windows update?

Answer (score 3):

According to [MSDN](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_update/does-windows-provide-a-way-to-uninstall-security/b616c77d-609c-4ca1-b6f9-5f14b661166e), in order to uninstall update #980302, you should use the command:

```
wusa /uninstall /kb:980302
```

As the documentation and `wusa /?` doesen't reveal anything about specifying more `/kb`s, your batch file should consist of several above lines (one per kb#).

Don't forget to run your batch file as Administrator!

Answer (score 0):

[wusa](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/934307) can uninstall by KB number:

```
wusa /uninstall /kb 123456
```